# Hammer Js Not working with Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, hammer.js

I have problem in implementing touch events with backbone.js and hammer.js

I have tried implementing the touch in the conventional way i.e defining the touch events in "events" section.But it has not worked for me.

Please find my code below

```
define(['Backbone','underscore','Handlebars','Hammer'],function(Backbone,_,Handlebars,Hammer) {
//getting the type of device in a variable using "userAgent"
window.MOBILE = navigator.userAgent.match(/mobile/i);   
var HeadderView = Backbone.View.extend(
{ 
 el: 'body',
 touchPrevents : false,
 initialize: function() 
 {
   this.el$ = $(this.el);
  },
   events: function() {//returning different functions based on the device
    return MOBILE ? 
       {
         'tap #headcontent': 'handleTap',
       } : 
       {
         'click #headcontent':'clickbackbone',
       }
  },
//declaring the corresponding functions 
  handleTap: function(){
  alert("tap event");
  },
  clickbackbone:function(){
   alert('backbone click');
   },
   render: function () 
    { 
//rendering the template and appending it to the page
      var that = this;
          require(['text!gaming/gameHeadder/headder.html'],function(HeaderTemplate){
          var template = Handlebars.compile(HeaderTemplate);
          var context = {title: "Tick Tack Toe", imageURL: "images/logo.jpg"}
      var htmlTemplate = template(context);
          that.el$.html( htmlTemplate);
        });
       },
     });
    return new HeadderView();
  }
);
```

Can some one help me out and correct my code

Comment: Where do you call Hammer?

Answer (score 0):

This is not how Hammer works. Backbone knows nothing about HammerJS.

If you really want to use Backbone-style event delegation with Hammer, you might want to check out the [backbone.hammer](https://github.com/wookiehangover/backbone.hammer) project.